# Golang: print string array in an unique way

Tags: string, go, format, slice

I want a function `func format(s []string) string` such that for two string slices `s1` and `s2`, if `reflect.DeepEqual(s1, s2) == false`, then `format(s1) != format(s2)`.

If I simply use `fmt.Sprint`, slices `["a", "b", "c"]` and `["a b", "c"]` are all printed as `[a b c]`, which is undesirable; and there is also the problem of `string([]byte('4', 0, '2'))` having the same representation as `"42"`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a format verb that shows the data structure, like `%#v`. In this case `%q` works well too because the primitive types are all strings.

```
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", []string{"a", "b", "c"})
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", []string{"a b", "c"})

// prints
// []string{"a", "b", "c"}
// []string{"a b", "c"}
```

Comment: Ha, that's a very good solution — I should have read https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/ more closely. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may use:

```golang
func format(s1, s2 []string) string {
    if reflect.DeepEqual(s1, s2) {
        return "%v\n"
    }
    return "%q\n"
}
```

Like this working sample ([The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/xVSITZKBCM)):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    s1, s2 := []string{"a", "b", "c"}, []string{"a b", "c"}
    frmat := format(s1, s2)
    fmt.Printf(frmat, s1) // ["a" "b" "c"]
    fmt.Printf(frmat, s2) // ["a b" "c"]

    s2 = []string{"a", "b", "c"}
    frmat = format(s1, s2)
    fmt.Printf(frmat, s1) // ["a" "b" "c"]
    fmt.Printf(frmat, s2) // ["a b" "c"]
}

func format(s1, s2 []string) string {
    if reflect.DeepEqual(s1, s2) {
        return "%v\n"
    }
    return "%q\n"
}
```

output:

```
["a" "b" "c"]
["a b" "c"]
[a b c]
[a b c]
```

Comment: Your answers are way too long and (perhaps unnecessarily) illustrative even when the question requires a short answer with perhaps 1-2 lines of code. I up voted nevertheless to convey no offence as I've learned quite a bit from your other answers.